# Bash script to check if given number is float or not using regular expressions

Tags: bash, shell

I've written a simple script that checks if a given number is float. But it isn't working quite opposite. Here's the code:

```
#! /bin/bash

main () {
  if [[ "$1" == ^[0-9]+\.?[0-9]+ ]]
  then
    echo "Floating number"
  else
    echo "Not a floating number"
  fi
}

main "$@"
```

When I'm giving a floating-point number, it's executing else part. Here's the output:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCBLK.jpg)

Comment: Note that the question I closed this as a duplicate of explicitly has answers covering floating-point using regexes, so even though its title is less explicit, it does indeed cover the relevant space.

Comment: As a one-sentence answer: `==` is a glob-style match, not a regex match; use `=~`. (Also, `==` shouldn't be used in a non-arithmetic operator in bash at all; the POSIX-standard string comparison operator is `=`; using it even in `[[` helps keep finger memory for writing correct code for `/bin/sh`).

Comment: Also -- post the output as text, same as how you posted the code. See [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) on [meta].

Comment: Thank you, Charles! I will not upload images going further.